# How do I not show my real name when commenting in a Google Doc, while signed in to my Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, google-docs, privacy

I have a Gmail account and it has my real name on it. I don't know how to keep everyone from seeing my real name if they visit my account. I also do not know how to keep people from seeing my name when commenting on a Google doc. I just want people to see my screen name, and that's it. I've found out how to keep people from seeing my name when I email them. How do I keep my secrecy?

Answer (score 4):

If you open the doc and comment from an incognito tab, the comment will post anonymously.

To open an incognito tab, type Ctrl+Shift+N (Windows, Linux, Chrome OS) or Command-Shift-N (Mac).

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to remain private in Google Docs while being signed on. Your only option is to sign out and visit the link which will allow you to comment as an anonymous user.