# How can I hide my name on a shared Google Doc?

Tags: google-docs, google-account, privacy, google-drive-sharing

Just realized my name is clear as day on my documents that I'm sharing with strangers.  Meanwhile they all show up as "Anonymous %animal%".  How do I make it so my name doesn't show up?

Comment: Seems to be strongly related: [How do I not show my real name when commenting in a Google Doc, while signed in to my Gmail account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/60812/354)

Comment: Doesn't really offer a solution though.

Comment: @V2Blast See [Anonymous or unknown people in a file](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494888?hl=en)

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible to hide the owner name on shared documents. It could be found either on the Google Documents UI or on Google Drive.

The alternative is to use an account that doesn't include your name on the email address nor the display name.

If you will not allow strangers to edit your documents, another alternative is to publish your files to the web.

Comment: You may also want to explain how/when viewers are displayed as "Anonymous [Animal]" (even if this can't be done to hide the file owner's identity).

Comment: [Here's the relevant Google help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494888?hl=en) that explains how this feature works: "If you share or open a file with a link, you may not see the names of people who view it.
 - People you didn’t invite individually will show as anonymous animals when they’re in the file.
- People you invite individually will show by name when they’re in the file. 
You can only see other people’s names when you give them individual permission to view a file or if they are part of a mailing list."

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Google account, go to privacy.
Change/Hide your name/email by logging in.

I don't know about the "anonymous" thing, but if you were to hide your email/change your name you wouldn't feel the pressure.

Comment: [Here's the relevant Google help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494888?hl=en) that explains how this feature works: "If you share or open a file with a link, you may not see the names of people who view it.
 - People you didn’t invite individually will show as anonymous animals when they’re in the file.
- People you invite individually will show by name when they’re in the file. 
You can only see other people’s names when you give them individual permission to view a file or if they are part of a mailing list." It won't hide the file owner's identity, though.